# Calculate row in Excel 2 times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate these lines:

```
I3 + 2*J3 + K3
```

I managed to create this so far: `=SUM(I3:K3)`

How I can calculate the total using my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. Don't forget you can do comma-separated cells, not just ranges.

=SUM(I3,(PRODUCT(2,J3)),K3)

Comment: Is this valid formula? =SUM(I13 + 2*J13 + K13)

Comment: Excel seems to be able to distinguish between defined functions and operand-driven calculations. Using your formula above, which works, this also works: =I13 + 2*J13 + K13

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution would be...
=(I3+(2*J3)+K3)